# Why I cannot use --position on MySql like this?

Tags: mysql, linux

Can somebody guide me here, why am I getting this error? and how do I solve it??

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--position 15 87, stu_id char(9) PRIMARY KEY, stu_fname char(20) ' at line 1
```

Following query I tried to run;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STid( - - position1587,
stu_idchar( 9 ) PRIMARY KEY ,
stu_fnamechar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
stu_lnamechar( 20 ) NOT NULL
);
```

Info:

```
user@wserver:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html):

> ... the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax ...